# PyQt5 application does not show the widgets properly on a different machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, screen-resolution

I just made an executable of a PyQt5 app via `pyinstaller`. The .exe file runs like a charm on my machine. I also ran `app.py` on the second machine, the result is same.

However, I sent it to my laptop to see is it working on another machine. The app is working, yet the widgets are in chaos mode. (Both machines are Windows 10)

**QLineEdits** width-height broken, because of this they are blocking some QLabels.

**Buttons** are smaller than normal size.

The whole **MainWindow** is smaller.

**QMessageBox**es are broken, their width-height completely changed.

**QLabels** size are normal.

Resolutions are different on these machines, but since I set the size of MainWindow by

```
self.setFixedSize(width,height)
```

And set the size of other widgets using `setGeometry()`, I thought it'll show the widgets as same on my main machine.

**Note:** The size of the MainWindow and widgets is not bigger than the resolution of the other machine. It should fit without any problem.

How to set PyQt5 properly so the app works same in all machines -at least Windows installed machines- so the widgets doesn't go crazy and all sizes stays same?

Comment: `pyinstaller` is not good to `PyQt`.Unsolved problem often happens...as far as I know.here is a [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567832/i-changed-python-gui-into-exe-file-by-pyinstaller-and-in-that-exe-file-i-canno] `QMultimedia` doesn't emit sounds ... If you don't mind,you may as well use other thing.